# The probability of a white ball

Tags: probability-theory

A large urn has n balls. Each ball is equiprobably white or black. A random ball is withdrawn from the urn. The ball is white. The ball is returned to the urn. The contents of the urn is stirred. Another random ball is withdrawn from the urn. What is the probability that the ball is white?

Comment: It seems like this question is concerned with the idea of replacement and independent events, so essentially the probability of a white ball is just the proportion of white balls in the urn.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are $w$ white balls. Then there are $n-w$ black balls. Drawing a white ball and then returning it and stirring the urn gives us no additional information. So the probability of drawing a white ball again is $w/n$.

Comment: As n approaches 1, the probability that the ball is white approaches 1. As n moves to infinity, the probability that the ball is white approaches 1/2. Is there a more rigorous formula?

Comment: It does give us some information: $w\geq1$

Answer (score 0):

---

The problem statement is not quite clear to me. I'm guessing that "each ball is equiprobably white or black" means that the number of white balls in the urn is a random variable with a symmetric binomial distribution; i.e., the urn contains a random sample of size $n$ from an infinite population of balls, half of which are white and half black. Two balls are drawn, one at a time, with replacement. We are asked for the conditional probability that the second ball is white, given that the first ball is white. I believe the answer is
$$\frac1n\cdot1+\frac{n-1}n\cdot\frac12=\frac{n+1}{2n}$$
since you have probability $\frac1n$ of getting the same ball on the second drawing.